# Custom image returning null from embedded resources

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to load an image from my solution which is embeded as a jpg but it says its not located.
I am declaring to the two images as such

```
Image selectedImage = null;
Image emptyImage = null;
selectedImage = Image.FromStream(System.Reflection.Assembly.
GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(@"selected.png"));

emptyImage = Image.FromStream(System.Reflection.Assembly
.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(@"empty.png"));
```

I need to custom draw a checkbox so it retains the style
You can see that the images are included in my solution

[image]

And both of them are selected as embedd resources
[image]

[image]

I am then using this custom function to draw the checkbox image onto an appointment

```
private void dxsourceNetAppointments_CustomDrawAppointment(object sender, CustomDrawObjectEventArgs e)
        {
            VerticalAppointmentViewInfo apptViewInfo = e.ObjectInfo as VerticalAppointmentViewInfo;
            if (apptViewInfo != null)
            {
                Rectangle imageBounds = GetImageBoundsFromViewInfo(apptViewInfo);
                e.DrawDefault();
                bool isCustomSelected = (bool)apptViewInfo.Appointment.CustomFields["CheckedIn"];
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(isCustomSelected ? selectedImage : emptyImage, imageBounds);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
  }
```

Any reason as to why my images might be null I thought u didnt have to supply the full path unless it was on disk?.

**Edit 2**

I tried a resource file but its also saying null for some reason

```
  selectedImage = WindowsFormsApplication1.SchedurlesImages.selected;
  emptyImage = WindowsFormsApplication1.SchedurlesImages.empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `GetManifestResourceStream`, you will need to qualify it with your assembly name, such as:

```
emptyImage = Image.FromStream(System.Reflection.Assembly
  .GetExecutingAssembly()
  .GetManifestResourceStream(@"SMBAScheduler.empty.png"));
```

Instead of using embedded resource, might I suggest using a RESX-based resource file? It will code generate a wrapper that you can directly use the static properties.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer can you provide an example without using GetManifiest without stream so just means I can grab the image

Comment: is there a better way of doing this can I not just draw a checkbox using gdi ? at all

Comment: @davidbuc use a resx file.

Comment: how would I reference the image then if I used a resource file

Comment: @davidbuc it will generate a class file: `YourResxResources.YourResourceName`.

Comment: Does it understand jpgs I see you have to use 

var bmp = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.myimage);

Comment: @davidbuc yep. try it. you won't also have to convert it to a bitmap.

Comment: see edit above mate still comming null weird they def there as a file see them in the file as well